# 2nf second normal form difficult exercise

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, normalization

I have R(A,B,C,D) with AB 
primary key and AD --> C

I think it is in 2nf becouse you cannot determine C with a subset of AB
from wiki  "a table is in 2NF if it is in 1NF and no non-prime attribute is dependent on any proper subset of any candidate key of the table"

but many people say it is in 1nf because the definition 
"in 2NF if it is in 1NF and every non-prime attribute of the table is dependent on the whole of every candidate key" 
so AD is not the whole primary key but just a part with another attribute not prime

please if you can put also some refereces different of wikipedia so I can demostrate my thesis if it is really correct

Comment: The fact that {AB} is a key means that AB->CD.

"A relation R is in second normal form if it is in first normal form
and every non-prime attribute of R is fully dependent on each
candidate key of R."
[1]

Therefore R does satisfy 2NF because every nonprime attribute (C,D) is fully dependent on every key ({A,B}).

[1] *Codd E. F., "Further Normalization of the Data Base Relational Model" in Randall J. Rustin (ed.), Data Base Systems: Courant Computer Science Symposia Series 6, Prentice-Hall, Englewood Cliffs, N.J., 1972.*

Answer (score 2):

You state as a fact that **AB** is the primary key for the given relation **R**. For that to be true there have to be at least one more functional dependency other than **AD->C** .

In order to explain 2NF, I assume that the missing FD is say **B->D**. So we have a relation R(A,B,C,D) with FD's :

AD->C
B->D

Then our primary key is **AB**. Now in simple words 2NF deals with *partial dependency*, that is, when an attribute depends on part of the primary key. (So if we have a primary key that's just one attribute than the relation R is already in 2NF!)

Formally:

Given a functional dependency **X->A** of a relation **R** where:

1. **X** is a *set* of attributes of **R**
2. **A** is a *non-prime* attribute not in **X**

then to be in 2NF, **X** should **not** be a proper subset of any key.

Coming back to our example. Primary key is **AB**. So primary attributes are **A** and **B**. Non primary attributes are **C** and **D**.

Let's consider the first FD, **AD->C**

Here **C** is a non primary attribute. To *not* violate 2NF condition, **AD** should *not* be a proper subset of the primary key **AB**. AD is not a proper subset of AB, so it does not violate 2NF condition.

Let's see the next FD, **B->D**

Here **D** is a non primary attribute and **B** is a proper subset of primary key **AB** and therefore it violates 2NF condition.

Hence the relation R is not in second normal form.

On the other hand if the set of FD's for **R** would have been:

AD->C
AB->D

Our primary key is still **AB** but now the relation R is in second normal form.

Comment: Great answer with both cases considered. Thanks.